# Georeferencing in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, georeferencing, arcgis-10.4

I am new to ArcMap.

I have bistatic MiniRF data. This data is not georeferenced. I want to make this georeference. Correspondence to each pixel, I have one latitude and longitude information in external file. I have an image of 1000x1000 size, and similarly, the latitude image is also 1000x1000, and the longitude image is 1000x1000.

How  I do georeferencing?

Comment: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/manage-data/raster-and-images/fundamentals-for-georeferencing-a-raster-dataset.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you are want a pixel based geo-referencing you have to convert the data into xyz table format from the lat, lon and value raster. Then, you can read the data as point in arcmap and convert it to raster from points.
or you can use the each corner latlon for geo-reference. It is better to any programming language like R or python, there you can perform this operation quickly.

Comment: Can you please give me one example code to perform  in python. Thanks

Comment: Ya sure. Please share something from where I can download this image. find me [here](https://subhadipdatta007.wixsite.com/profile/contact).

Comment: Please download the data from here. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/f713xij889ier9z/AAD4CH5vBKE5CrrWbEHaWQQca?dl=0

Comment: Here angle is the raster values? and the CRS?

Comment: Yes. I want to georeference angle according to latitude and longitude. Polar south Pole projection can be used for georeferencing.

Comment: can you provide me Proj4string or WKT of the CRS?

Comment: Hey, I have not Proj4string or WKT of the CRS. CRS can be used Spherical Polar format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109929/discussion-between-nidhi-verma-and-subhadip-datta).